# Boto3 stop_instances does it handle already stopped instances

Tags: boto3

I am writing a script to stop instances using `stop_instances()`, I tried finding to no avail, on the docs on what happens when an instance_id is **already stopped or does not exist.**

Any help?

Comment: "what happens when an instance_id is already stopped or does not exist" - please try and let as know.

Answer (score 0):

So i found:

If input ec2 instance id is wrong, the `stop_instance` will raise error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceID.Malformed) when calling the StopInstances operation: Invalid id: "i-00fbf4cd0b43cc9b4"
```

If instance id is missing, the `stop_instance` will raise error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceID.NotFound)
```

If instance id is already stopped, `stop_instances` will return:

```
{
   "StoppingInstances":[
      {
         "CurrentState":{
            "Code":80,
            "Name":"stopped"
         },
         "InstanceId":"i-0bcb28505bc274a1c",
         "PreviousState":{
            "Code":80,
            "Name":"stopped"
         }
      },
      {
         "CurrentState":{
            "Code":80,
            "Name":"stopped"
         },
         "InstanceId":"i-00fbf2cd0b43cc9b5",
         "PreviousState":{
            "Code":80,
            "Name":"stopped"
         }
      },
      {
         "CurrentState":{
            "Code":80,
            "Name":"stopped"
         },
         "InstanceId":"i-0024ba03138462f1c",
         "PreviousState":{
            "Code":80,
            "Name":"stopped"
         }
      }
   ],
   "ResponseMetadata":{
      "RequestId":"f8a20ae2-b469-4412-afbf-90d1a61efdec",
      "HTTPStatusCode":200,
      "HTTPHeaders":{
         "x-amzn-requestid":"f8a20ae2-b469-4412-afbf-90d1a61efdec",
         "cache-control":"no-cache, no-store",
         "strict-transport-security":"max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
         "content-type":"text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
         "content-length":"1254",
         "date":"Tue, 07 Jun 2022 05:06:30 GMT",
         "server":"AmazonEC2"
      },
      "RetryAttempts":0
   }
}
```

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/error-handling.html